# React useState with an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In react, setting state's value with the equal old's one is **guaranteed not triggering render**, right?

How about **storing an array** in state?
React compares the array by reference, not by values deeply.
So setting a new array with exactly the same values **still triggering render**.

I created a component that listening **a scroll event**.
Thus I need to use `useEffect` to attach & detach the **scroll event**.

On every scroll event, it determines which children are visible within scroll view,
and save the indices (an array of index) of the children into a state, something like this:

```
const [index, setIndex]     = useState(-1);
const [indices, setIndices] = useState([]);

/* ... */

useEffect(() => {
   const handleScroll = () => {
      const newIndex  : number   = calculateFirstVisibleChild();
      const newIndices: number[] = calculateVisibleChildren();

      // save the result:
      setIndex(newIndex);     // trigger render only if the value changes (works)
      setIndices(newIndices); // always trigger render (works but inefficient)
   }

   window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
   return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll); // cleanup
}, []); // no dep, execute once at startup
```

The problem are:
How to set the indices with the same values **without triggering the render**.
If the scrolling distance is small, the visible children is remain the same, so the function still returning the same values.

I cannot comparing the `indices` & `newIndices` before passing into `setIndices` because **it needs to be listed on the useEffect's dependencies**, thus causing the event listener detached & attached back unnecessarily every index/indices changes.

Here the screenshot of the component i'm trying to make:
[image]

Update: here the usage of the stored `index`/`indices`:
At this moment i use the `index` (single level).
I'm going to upgrade my `NavScroll` to multi level after the `indices` problem solved.

```
// the render:
.....map((child, i) => (
   <ListGroupItem
      key={i}

      active={(i === index)} // here the actual highlight works! true: highlight, false: normal
   >
   </ListGroupItem>
.....
```

Update:
I will convert the indices array into **comma separated string** to avoid triggering unnecessary render and **parse/convert back to array** when render.
I know this is *an ugly hack*, but it works.
Please help me solving with *the beauty way*.

Comment: Simply create two effects. One for attaching/detaching the event listener on component mount/unmount, and one for tracking changes to your state variables.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `calculateVisibleChildren()` returns an array, is that correct? If that's the case, then `newIndices` is essentially a new array even if all the elements are the same. So react will re-render.

Yet, I assume you are going to use the `indices` this way,

```
// render
return (
  <div>
    {indices.map(index => <SomeComponent  index={index} />)}
  </div>
);
```

If that's the case, you can wrap `SomeComponent` into `memo()`. i.e.

```
// SomeComponent.js
import { memo } from "react";

const SomeComponent = () => {
  return /* some components */;
}

export default memo(SomeComponent);
```

See the [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) about `memo` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

After I spent a day googling for the solution,
i found a `useReducer` hook. For me, it's the advanced version of `useState`.
The getter still the same as `useState`, but the setter has more control (cmiiw).

```
// const [activeIndices, setActiveIndices] = useState<number[]>([]); // bye-bye

const [activeIndices, setActiveIndices] = useReducer((indices: number[], newIndices: number[]): number[] => {
        if (deepEqual(newIndices, indices)) return indices; // already the same, use the old as by-reference
        return newIndices; // update with the new one
    }, []);
```